# Proper way to change body innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jscript

I'm doing some jQuery stuff in head. and at the end of file I change body innerHTML like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML='<div>some string</div><div>some string</div><div>some string</div>'+document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
```

After doing that the elements will be added to body  but none of jquery or javascript functions work. Do you know why and how to fix it?

Note: If "it is possible" I prefer to add elements to body with above  method

This is what I'm doing in head (it is datatables.net) for examle in this code after changing innerHTML the    `$('#search').keyup` won't work... .

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function() {
            $(document).ready(function() {

                oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "aaSorting": [
                        [1, 'asc']
                    ],

                    responsive: true
                });
                $('#search').keyup(function() {
                    oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();

                })

            });
        }); //]]>
    </script>
```

EDIT: Problem solved!

Comment: Show us your `jQuery` methods. I guess that you need to use delegate event handler in this case.

Comment: Instead of `$('#search').keyup(function()` use this `$('body').on('keyup', '#search', function()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally made two changes to make this work:
1 put all scripts near end of file
2 Execute all preparation codes after changing body innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

With dynamically added objects, you won't be abled to simply do:

```
$("#object").click(function(){

});
```

but instead, you need to use:

```
$(document).on("click", "#object", function(){

});
```

This way, you can trigger it dynamic added objects.